# get domain name from URL in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i am new with kibana and elastic search
I have 2 attribute in my index url:String Timestamp:epoch time
ex 
`1477879888  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`
i want to get maximum domain in every 1 hr interval 
i want to know how to get derived attribute domain name